# scala proxy macro, issue converting method args to values

Tags: scala, proxy, scala-macros

I am trying to write a proxy macro using scala macros. I want to be able to proxy a trait X and return instances of X that invoke a function for all methods of X.

Here is what I did so far. Say we want to proxy the trait TheTrait (which is defined below), we can run ProxyMacro.proxy passing a function that will be called for all invocations of the proxy methods.

```
    trait TheTrait
    {
        def myMethod(x: String)(y: Int): String
    }

    val proxy = ProxyMacro.proxy[TheTrait] {
        case ("myMethod", args) =>
            "ok"
    }
    println(proxy.myMethod("hello")(5))
```

The implementation so far is this:

```
package macrotests

import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

object ProxyMacro
{
type Implementor = (String, Any) => Any

def proxy[T](implementor: Implementor): T = macro impl[T]

def impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(implementor: c.Expr[Implementor]): c.Expr[T] = {
    import c.universe._

    val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]

    val decls = tpe.decls.map { decl =>
        val termName = decl.name.toTermName
        val method = decl.asMethod
        val params = method.paramLists.map(_.map(s => internal.valDef(s)))
        val paramVars = method.paramLists.flatMap(_.map { s =>
            internal.captureVariable(s)
            internal.referenceCapturedVariable(s)
        })

        q""" def $termName (...$params) = {
            $implementor (${termName.toString}, List(..${paramVars}) ).asInstanceOf[${method.returnType}]
           }"""
    }

    c.Expr[T] {
        q"""
      new $tpe {
        ..$decls
      }
  """
    }
}
```

}

But there is a problem. This doesn't compile due to List(..${paramVars}). This should just create a list with all the values of the method arguments.
But I get a compilation issue (not worth pasting it) on that line.

How can I convert the list of method arguments to their values?

Comment: can you tell me you want to the resulting code ,i use `show(decls.head )` the result is `def myMethod(x: String)(y: Int) = ((x0$1: String, x1$1: Any) => scala.Tuple2.apply[String, Any](x0$1, x1$1) match {case (_1: String, _2: Any)(String, Any)("myMethod", (args @ _)) => "ok"})("myMethod", List(ReferenceToBoxed(x), ReferenceToBoxed(y))).asInstanceOf[String]
`

Comment: That impl looks about right, ofcourse the macro should work for any trait and any number/type of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

showInfo is useful when you debug macro

`def showInfo(s: String) =
    c.info(c.enclosingPosition, s.split("\n").mkString("\n |---macro info---\n |", "\n |", ""), true)`

change

`val paramVars = method.paramLists.flatMap(_.map { s =>
            internal.captureVariable(s)
            internal.referenceCapturedVariable(s)
        })`(this result is `List(x0$1, x1$1)`)

to

`val paramVars = method.paramLists.flatMap(_.map { s =>
  s.name
})`(this result is `List(x, y)`)